# How to avoid [ngSwitch] when rendering child component by a variable value?

Tags: angular, selector

In my Angular 2 project I have an array of objects of following shape:

```
let blocks = [
  {'type':'app-component-type-1',data:{}},
  {'type':'app-component-type-2',data:{}}
]
```

I'm walking this array via standard `*ngFor`:

```
<div *ngFor="let block of blocks">
```

And then my problem comes: I am passing `block.data` to a child component, which has selector matching the value of `block.type`. I am currently doing it via `[ngSwitch]` as follows:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="block.type">
  <app-component-type-1 *ngSwitchCase="'app-component-type-1'" [data]="block.data"></app-component-type-1>
  <app-component-type-2 *ngSwitchCase="'app-component-type-2'" [data]="block.data"></app-component-type-2>
</div>
```

I think it's a bad approach, but I didn't find any way how to specify a child component's tag/selector through a variable value - something like:

```
<template [child-component-selector]="block.type" [data]="block.data"></template>
```

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: That's what `ngSwitchCase` is for. An alternative is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: It seems silly - I will have dozens of component types which will have the same I/O interface and the only difference will be their selector.